# WPF custom MaskControl issue

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, mask

Okay after being stuck on this for days now i decided to ask my question here. I've made a custom control that inherits from TextBox for a MaskControl. Now my issue i'm having is the following.

After some research i found that if you do this

```
MaskedTextBox Mask="999999.99"
```

that the 9 should be digits and be optional. So for example I enter 555 en hit Save, the Binding has a value of 555___ , __  . So i went back to the interwebs but after hours of searching i came up with nothing so that why I'm asking here.

I'll attach my code in a pastebin.
Thanks in advance

ControlClass
[MyMaskedTextBoxControl](http://pastebin.com/cqQp6Gff)

Comment: Why reinventing the Wheel? The [WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox) already has that.

Comment: Because the framework where i'm building on is custom made so i don't want to build 7 billion work around just to get it working

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Have you implemented your own .Net? Anyways you're still having a lot of workarounds to get your own stuff working, you know...

Comment: No no the controls in the framework I'm working are all custom. That's what i meant. I'll try the toolkit anyways

Comment: there must be a `STRONG`, I mean a `REALLY STRONG` reason that justifies inheriting from the default WPF controls. I would like to know what yours is...

Comment: Like i said the controls of the framework i'm programming in are custom .. Don't blame me.. i just removed the controls name from my pastebin because i can't post it online anyway